# fogbugz, svn integration not working. (svn hosted on wush.net)

Tags: svn, fogbugz, websvn

I just switched two projects over to fogbugz and so far I like it a lot.  FB has a few features that just blow trac out of the water.  However, I am having trouble getting FB to point back to the revisions from within the FB issues.

I have set up the bugid in tortoisesvn and that all works - I can click on a bugid in the GUI and a fogbugz browser pops up with the correct issue.  The reverse does not work however.

I am using wush for my svn hosting.
I have looked at
http://fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/sourcecontrol/setup/Subversion.html

and

https://support.wush.net/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=33&nav=0

but have not figured out how to do it correctly.  I set the websvn guest account to have read access to the repo.

The integrateion between trac and svn worked fine.  I was able (from trac ticket) to see the source that changed in a revision that was linked to a comment in a SVN commit.

Has anyone had success with FB integration with wush hosting of websvn/SVN?

EDIT:

I would also be happy to just be able to have a link or a reference or even text put in the FB issue.  However, it doesn;t seem that the FB issue is even touched by a commit.

EDIT: 
In response to one poster:

The bugid is shown correctly in the svnUI - that is, I can click on a link in the history of the tortoisesvn and it brings up the url in fogbugz.

What is not working is:

- auto updating/insertion of checkin comment into a FB issue
- in FB, no link back to the repo/changes/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"auto updating/insertion of checkin comment into a FB issue"

Since that isn't working, it means the hook commit script is not firing or cannot reach your FogBugz server.

See this:
http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/blog/post/Debugging-Subversion-Source-Control-Integration.aspx

EDIT:

Thanks - I am editing this because I want to add one bit, then vote for this answer.

I finally got it working. There was a little tweak in the standard url I had to change and I had to send the post commit script to my provider.

[Here is the url that finally got it all together for me](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/sourcecontrol/setup/Subversion.html)

This one helps too 
http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/advanced/SourceControlIntegration.html

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I got support from Rich I believe and I will get to this.  Such service!  It is definitely some mechanical issue that was not correct.  I'll hopefully get to it soon.

Answer (score 1):

We successfully have FogBugz working with SVN although our SVN is hosted locally. I'm not sure form your question which part your having problems with so I'll describe what we had to do to make it work.

It took a while to correctly configure the source control URL in FogBugz but starting from basics we built this up until we got what we wanted.

It also took some time to create the script in the hooks folder and we had to customize each one and hard-code it to the right repository as it didn't seem to create the correct URL dynamically. We also had to check that the build server had Internet access to the FogBugz URL as we are behind a corporate firewall. Perhaps this is the issue? I do not know much about WUSH but will it include Internet access to perform the HTTP get to FogBugz?

If you add further detail to your question I'll try to help but I'll admit I've only set up the integration once so I'm not an expert - perhaps FogBugz support is your best option.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks.  FB is hosted by Fogcreek, wush is an svn hosting site.  I doubt the firewall is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working.  There was a little tweak i n the standard url I had to change and I had to send the post commit script to my provider.

[Here is the url that finally got it all together for me](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/sourcecontrol/setup/Subversion.html)

This one helps too
http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/advanced/SourceControlIntegration.html